# Name a New Sheet Based on Existing Sheet Names

Tags: excel, vba

I have worksheets named "Chart 1", "Chart 2", "Chart 3" and "Custom Chart". I want to make a copy of "Custom Chart" and name it "Custom 1". I want to do this indefinitely such that successive copies are named "Custom 2", "Custom 3", etc. My code successfully makes the copies, but fails to name them as intended. The problem is the While-End loop. VBA rejects it because the condition is not boolean. How can I alter this code to name the new copies according to my rules?

```
Sub CustomChartCopy()
'Copy the Custom Chart to a new worksheet to preserve it
'Note: The original data series are preserved, but no longer change with the Custom Chart macro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

j = 1

Set CustomChart = Sheets("Custom Chart")

CustomChart.ChartArea.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

With ActiveSheet
    .Paste
    .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
End With

ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

'delete the blank last sheet of the workbook
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
End With

'Name the new chart copy
While Not InStr(ws.name, j)
    ActiveChart.name = "Custom " & j
    j = j + 1
End While

ActiveSheet.Move _
    After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Custom Chart")

ActiveWindow.zoom = 140

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CustomChartCopy()
'Copy the Custom Chart to a new worksheet to preserve it
'Note: The original data series are preserved, but no longer change with the Custom Chart macro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim j As Integer
'Dim ws As Worksheet

Set CustomChart = Sheets("Custom Chart")

CustomChart.ChartArea.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

With ActiveSheet
    .Paste
    .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
End With

ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet

'delete the blank last sheet of the workbook
With ActiveWorkbook
    .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Delete
End With

'move the custom chart copy
ActiveSheet.Move _
    Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("EIRP LL Archive")

're name the custom chart copy
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
j = 1
Start:
ActiveSheet.name = "Custom" & j
ActiveWindow.zoom = 140
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
j = j + 1
Resume Start

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Max,

Replace End While with Wend

'---

Comment: thanks. VBA accepts Wend, but it does not accept While Not InStr(ws.name) because it is not a boolean. I was hoping for an alternative that fixes that.

Comment: You have not told Excel what worksheet the WS variable applies to...
  Set WS = ActiveSheet or Set WS = Worksheets(j) or ...
Be careful, as the loop could run without stopping.
Make sure you have some way to force an exit.